# Как изменить размер (высоту) у svg

Tags: css3, html5

`svg` имеет высоту самой картинки, а также просто прозрачный фон, как его убрать?

Вот полный исходник

`html` - https://pastebin.com/8HWdxfMf

`css` - https://pastebin.com/Wn0jEje8

> html

```
<a href=#><img class=VK_link <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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"/></a>
```

> css

```
a{
    display:flex;
    outline:0px black solid;
    float:left;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    height:60px;
    transition: .2s all;
}
.VK_link{
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:110px
}
body a img{
    width:50px;
    padding:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mysvg {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mysvg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 96.496 96.496" xml:space="preserve">
 <path d="M92.499,65.178c-2.873-3.446-6.254-6.387-9.453-9.51c-2.886-2.815-3.068-4.448-0.748-7.697   c2.532-3.546,5.255-6.956,7.81-10.486c2.385-3.299,4.823-6.589,6.078-10.539c0.796-2.513,0.092-3.623-2.485-4.063   c-0.444-0.077-0.903-0.081-1.355-0.081l-15.289-0.018c-1.883-0.028-2.924,0.793-3.59,2.462c-0.899,2.256-1.826,4.51-2.897,6.687   c-2.43,4.936-5.144,9.707-8.949,13.747c-0.839,0.891-1.767,2.017-3.169,1.553c-1.754-0.64-2.271-3.53-2.242-4.507l-0.015-17.647   c-0.34-2.521-0.899-3.645-3.402-4.135l-15.882,0.003c-2.12,0-3.183,0.819-4.315,2.145c-0.653,0.766-0.85,1.263,0.492,1.517   c2.636,0.5,4.121,2.206,4.515,4.849c0.632,4.223,0.588,8.463,0.224,12.703c-0.107,1.238-0.32,2.473-0.811,3.629   c-0.768,1.817-2.008,2.187-3.637,1.069c-1.475-1.012-2.511-2.44-3.525-3.874c-3.809-5.382-6.848-11.186-9.326-17.285   c-0.716-1.762-1.951-2.83-3.818-2.859c-4.587-0.073-9.175-0.085-13.762,0.004c-2.76,0.052-3.583,1.392-2.459,3.894   c4.996,11.113,10.557,21.917,17.816,31.759c3.727,5.051,8.006,9.51,13.534,12.67c6.265,3.582,13.009,4.66,20.112,4.328   c3.326-0.156,4.325-1.021,4.479-4.336c0.104-2.268,0.361-4.523,1.48-6.561c1.098-2,2.761-2.381,4.678-1.137   c0.959,0.623,1.767,1.416,2.53,2.252c1.872,2.048,3.677,4.158,5.62,6.137c2.437,2.48,5.324,3.945,8.954,3.646L93.744,75.5   c2.264-0.148,3.438-2.924,2.138-5.451C94.969,68.279,93.771,66.703,92.499,65.178z" fill="#000000"/>
</svg>
</div>
```